# Can't upload archive to app store since yesterday

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, iad

2 days before I successfully uploaded the archive for my application and my application is on app store, but yesterday and today when I upload the archive I see "Uploading the archive" message (with subtitle "Sending api usage to itunes connect") at the beggining, but then I see "iTunes Store operation failed. This action couldn't be completed. Try again later" :

[image]

When I try to upload the archive for another application, everything is OK, it's very strange, because since 2 days ago I only changed the minimum age in the application from 17 to 18 (so I didn't change everything important in the application settings).

May be in happen because we use iAd network and apple notified that this network will be unavailable since July ?

[image]

Comment: Okey then did you try to remove the iAad from your application?

Comment: Yes, I tried it right now, it didn't help

Comment: @PaulGalavic check my answer, Make sure Application loader version must be >= 3.0

Comment: I waited for 3 days to solve this bug... this is how i solved it
step 1. Click "upload to app store"
step 2. PRAY ! (most important step)
step 3. repeat step 1 and 2 till upload successful. (could take 5 to 6 attempts, don't give up yet :P)

As an android developer this is why i hate developing iOS.

p.s: I had problem with application loaded as it broke my export compliance.
Also increased the build number by +1 not sure if that helped. lol

Comment: [That is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881883/not-able-to-upload-app-in-appstore-why-this-happen/55882324#55882324) worked for me, May anyone can try it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

just upload the ipa with Application Loader 2.9.1, even thought the apple tell you that you should upload the ipa with xcode 7.2 or Application Load 3.0.0, but , my solution works well
download Application Loader 2.9.1

Comment: Could you give the link?

Comment: In more modern versions of XCode, you'll find "Application Loader" under the "Xcode" menu (the first menu to the right of the Apple in the menu bar) and it'll be hiding in the "Open Developer Tools" submenu.

Comment: Actually it helped (I uploaded with the default Application Loader in my xCode 7.2), thank you very much

Comment: The current Application Loader that ships with XCode 7.3 fixed this for me, no need to download an old version

Comment: Where can I get / how can I generate the ipa file?

Comment: You have to choose Product->Archive. Then you need to choose your archive and press Export button. Then choose "Save for iOS app store deployment" and press Next. After that you need to follow the instruction

Answer (score 24):

Try this
**Xcode** -> **Open Developer Tool** -> **Application Loader** -> **Login with AppleID** -> Choose your app IPA
may this help you

Comment: where is my IPA after I build the app?

Comment: You can create IPA with this things.
Product - > Archive and wait for Archiving. When it successfully it will open dialog box for archive information. In this right side you will select EXPORT and "Save for Ad Hoc development"

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya : Save for "Ad Hoc" or save for "App Store" distribution ?

Comment: @Pushkraj Save for "Ad Hoc".

Answer (score 8):

Another solution that might help is disabling bitcode when submitting the IPA through XCode. Not sure why but this worked for my colleague when he had the same issue. If you want to keep bitcode then Application Loader will work, as pradip kikani pointed out.

Comment: After trying ~10 times, disabling bitcode did it for me. Strange.

Comment: Same here. Really strange. Worked though.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this exact problem TWICE yesterday (14th April 2016) using Xcode 7.2. 
I'd get either a

> "This action couldn't be completed. Try again later"

or a

> "This action couldn't be completed. Try again. (-22421)"

which one appeared to be random.  I just kept trying and trying and eventually the upload succeeded in both cases.  Apple are obviously being a bit ****.

Not the most technical useful answer but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: I tried 3 times yesterday, one 2 times this morning. Always having  This action couldn't be completed. Try again. (-22421)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue today when I wanted to validate my app in Xcode 7.3.1. In my case, my provisiong profiles had all expired on May 01, 2016 as I found out in the Xcode "Preferences > Accounts > View Details". I clicked on "Download All" and got renewed profiles with an updated expiry date.

Answer (score 3):

I tried restarting my mac and all that but nothing helped.

What actually worked for me :

1. Logged out from my developer account in Xcode preferences.
2. Turn off bitCode from build settings.
3. Changed the provisioning profile.

But im not sure which one of the methods worked cause i did them all at ones. 
good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Got Same issue today!! I found there is no "arm64" in my valid Architectures.instead there was one "arm6". 
Updated Valid Architecture list resolved my problem.

[image]

Comment: ok, but I had arm64 architecture, so it didn't cause any problems for me

Comment: @PaulGalavic Edited my answer. I think a spell error in plist cause this issue!! not sure.

Answer (score 2):

While facing such issue you should take care of some points listed below:

- Make sure you have added correct bundle ID & provisioning in to App
- If it is correct than might be after updating it on developer account it was not updated on Xcode. So in that case go to Xcode > Preferences > remove Account & Add it again. Clean Xcode set provisioning in targets & Projects both
- Once you done with above steps clean project & Prepare New Archive again & try to submit it

**Important Notes:**

- Do not try to submit Build files from Beta Xcode versions
- If you are using Application loader than make sure its version is greater than or equals to 3.0

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by changing the build number from `1.0` to `1.1`.