# iTunes connect upload build issues

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

i couldn't upload build in the iTunes connect and it is giving error like in the image. has any one faced the issue.[image]

Comment: you are trying with directly by xcode@Aarif

Comment: i am uploading update of app

Comment: Use application loader to upload the app

Comment: ok. but why it is coming?

Comment: some times apple server not respond or your internet is slow for uploading . there is lot of reason @Aarif

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35448039/3515115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove Provisioning Profiles files at ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
Make new Build and Archive the app. Xcode will create new Provisioning Profiles and submit the app to iTunesConnect.

If the issue exists, try validating the Archive.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application Loader :

[image]

**1.** To upload a build with Application Loader, launch the application on your machine and login to `iTunes Connect`.

[image]

**2.** Click on the large button labeled "Deliver Your App" and then click on the "Choose" button.

[image]

**3.** Select the "AppStore_x.x.ipa" file that sits inside the ".tgz" file you downloaded from the Mag+ Publish Portal.

[image]

**4.** You will see a summary of the app to be uploaded. Click on the "Next" button.

[image]

**5.** A progress bar will show the progress of your upload. Once complete, your build will be listed under your app in iTunes Connect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, Make sure you have selected correct account to upload app and also check for credentials, also make a habit of validating app before upload.

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify the I-tunes id before submitting.
You can try with removing account from xcode & add it again 
as below -

```
Xcode->Preference->Accounts
```

and attach provisioning profile accordingly.