# Not able to upload app in AppStore, why this happen?

Tags: ios, app-store

[image: I am getting this error while uploading app to AppStore from my MacBook]

Any specific reason why i am not able to upload app? And how to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same error, I remove network configuration and reconfigured it,
 from **system preference -> Network  -> from minus sign at bottom**, remove wifi connection and then click on plus sign to configure it and resubmit your app again.

Comment: Weird but amazing solutions, you saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: is there any permanent solutions? i am facing this issue again.

Comment: May it's related to your entire network configuration(s).

Comment: can you please explain a bit?

Comment: May it in your routers or your network admined by another or ISP.

Comment: I will figure it out what exactly and also share that as well. By the way thank you so much for help :)